# Is this a valid query? I am using MSSQL Server 2005

Tags: php, sql-server

Basically I am asking is there a better way to do the query `SELECT Name, Num .....` 
I believe it's not the way it should be in terms of syntax/structure? It is working, however, I wanna know if you can suggest me a better way to do it? I am talking about the query since I believe everything else is okay. Please let me know.

```
function ShowHolder()
{
    $db = $this->database[BBA];

    $this->setName(NULL, 1);

    $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT Name, Num FROM INFO WHERE Num = (SELECT sNomer FROM SIEGE)');
    if ($num_rows == -1)
    {
        $db->getError();
        return;
    }

    while ($row = $db->doRead())
    {
        $name = trim($row['Name']);
        $id_num = intval($row['Num']);
        $this->setName($name, $id_num);
    }
}

function setName($name, $id_num)
{
    Template::SetVar('HOLDER', $name == NULL ? 'N/A' : '<a href="./?index=holder&id=' . $id_num . '" class="largeFont">' . $name . '</a>');
}
```

Comment: I am not a big database guru, but i think, this is totally acceptable. Pros will tell you.

Comment: use joins as suggested by @Alex k its the better way..

Comment: `WHERE Num = (SELECT sNomer FROM SIEGE)` is valid but will fail if there is more than one entry in `SIEGE` in that case it should be `WHERE Num IN (...)`

Comment: This `SIEGE` table has only one row ?

Comment: Yes, it always has only one row. So, is this valid one in that case, so it shouldn't fail? I mean overall is the script fine? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script and query seem fine. As DrCopyPaste said, you might want to change `WHERE Num =` to `WHERE Num IN` just to have some certainty that it will work regardless of the number of rows in the `SIEGE` table. This might just be the simplest answer I've submitted.

Comment: So, even if It's supposed only to have one row in table `SIEGE`, it will be better to change it to `IN` overall? And the rest in the script, seems okay?

Comment: Yes change it to `IN`. It's a safety thing. And good practice.

Comment: Alright, before I accept the answer, could you be so kind to let me know overall if the script seems fine in syntax/structure? Will be so much appreciated.

Comment: @Monk25 Yes. Like Jake said. It's about good programming practice and writing future-proof code.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. Oh, and BTW: if there are no rows for it, it will set to `NULL` as according to the script and display `N/A` right? I am aware if `-1` rows that it will throw error message however for `0 rows`, it will be set to `NULL = N/A` right?

Comment: @Monk25 Yes, if there are 0 rows the `while` loop won't execute and as per your code it will remain set to `NULL = N/A`.